# Next JS, Back behaviour not called getInitialProps()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

Iam learning Next js and i use Express for custom server, and i want to call `getInitialProps()` method for `getter` or `setter` the HttpOnly Cookies. 
When go trigger back behaviour on browser `getInitialProps()` is not called.
Someone can help me or any solution for **call** SSR Function `getInitialProps()` ?? Like disable shallow render maybe or etc. 
Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Next JS version 9, you can use `getServerSideProps` - The way this would work is explained below

> Only runs on server-side getServerSideProps only runs on server-side
> and never runs on the browser. If a page uses getServerSideProps ,
> then:
>
> When you request this page directly, getServerSideProps runs at the
> request time, and this page will be pre-rendered with the returned
> props. When you request this page on client-side page transitions
> through next/link (documentation) or next/router (documentation),
> Next.js sends an API request to the server, which runs
> getServerSideProps. It’ll return JSON that contains the result of
> running getServerSideProps, and the JSON will be used to render the
> page. All this work will be handled automatically by Next.js, so you
> don’t need to do anything extra as long as you have getServerSideProps
> defined. You can use this tool to verify what Next.js eliminates from
> the client-side bundle.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-runs-on-server-side

Comment: Thanks for comment, sorry i miss understanding with u. When back behaviour is triggered that method is called bro ?

Comment: Are when back behaviour is request again to server ? Iam already read the docs. That route is link

Comment: Btw iam appreciate your answer

Comment: Thanks alot, that method getServerSideProps() work also in back behaviour. Solved